# Exclude SVG from gulp-svg-sprite build process

Tags: svg, gulp, icons, sprite, svg-sprite

I'm currently building an SVG Icon system using gulp-svg-sprite and have run into a situation where I need to exclude some icons from the build process.

Is there a way to EXCLUDE an SVG from running through these 2 pipes? Somehow I need to get the src filename and compare it to the SVG I want to exclude and so something like:

```
if src != svgToExclude then run the pipes.
```

I don't want specific icons being optimized via SVGO and other plugins for those 1-off SVG's that require 2 styleable paths.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const svgo = require('gulp-svgo');
const rsp = require('remove-svg-properties').stream;
const dom = require('gulp-dom');
const xmlEdit = require('gulp-edit-xml');
const gulpIf = require('gulp-if');
const gulpIgnore = require('gulp-ignore');
const { toPath } = require('svg-points');

var excludeIcon = './utilities/checkbox-checked/checkbox-checked--s.svg';

const svgBuild = src => {
  return gulp
    .src(src)
    .pipe(
      rsp.remove({
        properties: ['fill', rsp.PROPS_STROKE],
        log: false,
      })
    )
    .pipe(
      svgo({
        js2svg: {
          indent: 2,
          pretty: true,
        },
        plugins: [{ removeTitle: true }],
      })
    )
};

module.exports = svgBuild;
```

I'm new to gulp & node so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
- Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Using [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter):

```
const filter = require('gulp-filter');
```

something like

```
var excludeIconArray = ["iconToExclude1.svg", "iconToExclude2.svg", etc.]

const svgBuild = src => {

  const svgFilter = filter(file => {

    // will probably need file.path string manipulations here
    // file.path is the full path but you can select portions of it
    //  so the below is just pseudocode

    return !excludeIconArray.includes(file.path)
});

  return gulp
    .src(src)

// put the next pipe wherever you want to exclude certain files
// either right after source or just before the svgo pipe

.pipe(svgFilter())
```